# Best Practice to toggle Childcomponent from Parent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-functional-component

I created a toast notification in React which is Toggleable via the *timeNotification* function. For testing purposes, I used a button in the same Component to toggle the notification. All the notification does is to set a CSS class to "active" and after 5 seconds remove it.

```
  const timeNotification = () => {
    setShowNotification(true);
    setShowProgressBar(true)
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowNotification(false)
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowProgressBar(false)
    }, 5300)
  }
```

my goal is to make this Component triggerable in my React app whenever I need it. For example, when I require the user to log in to my website and the backend server is not reachable it is supposed to use my Notification component to send an error to the user.

What is the best practice to do so?
The first idea was to simply pass a function from the child to the parent component which is a bad practice because as far as I know functionality should always be passed down and never upwards.

The second idea was to toggle the component via useEffect

```
  useEffect(()=> {
    timeNotification()
  }, [])
```

This approach only works once. But after the Component is rendered for the first time, it just vanishes (gets moved out of the user's view). This approach would work if Id make the component un render after 5 seconds and rerender it as soon as a new error occurs which is also a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution, I still don't know if it's the best practice however it works. I did use the useEffect hook in the Child component.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    timeNotification();
  }, [props.refresh])
```

its triggered by the Parent via props and useState

```
const [showLoginError, setShowLoginError] = useState<number>(0);
setShowLoginError(prev => prev + 1)
```

when ever the parent increases the showLoginError the Notification useEffect gets triggered